# can I sort the order of data being returned from filter function

Tags: arrays, sorting, google-sheets, filter, google-sheets-query

I am using the filter function to filter a subset of data which works perfect.  However, I really need that data to be output in a particular order, in this case based on the value in one of the fields.

if you have the following data set

```
Name    Qty Flag
Frank   2   
Ted     5   
Sally   10  
Jojo    11  
Frank   5   
Frank   5435    
Frank   124 x
```

filtered for Frank

```
=FILTER(A4:B10,A4:A10 ="Frank")
```

I the desired output and order would look like this  - note that the records with an "x" in flag show up first.

```
Frank   5435

Frank   5

Frank   2

Frank   124
```

Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: you mean last not first, right?

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=QUERY({
 IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(A:B, A:A="Frank", C:C<>"x"), 2, 0), {"",""}); 
 IFERROR(SORT(FILTER(A:B, A:A="Frank", C:C ="x"), 2, 0), {"",""})}, 
 "where Col1 is not null", 0)
```

[image: 01]

Answer (score 1):

I think this will also work:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(ARRAY_CONSTRAIN(QUERY({A:B,{C1;IF(C2:C="x",9^9,1)}},"select Col1,Col2,Col2/Col3 where Col1='Frank' order by Col2/Col3 desc",1),9^9,2))
```

[image]